# Show QuickContact dialog

Tags: android, contacts, quickcontactbadge, quickcontact

I have a Contact List app, where I need to asign to the contacts name the function to show QuickContact dialog window when touching it:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

At this moment, I do this procesing the QuickContactBadge that appears as a contact's thumbnail. This is, when I touch the thumbnail, it appears this dialog window.

This is the code snippet:

```
public class ContactsListFragment extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
...

    private class ContactsAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements SectionIndexer {
    ...

        /** Generates the contact lookup Uri*/
        final Uri contactUri = Contacts.getLookupUri(
                cursor.getLong(ContactsQuery.ID),
                cursor.getString(ContactsQuery.LOOKUP_KEY));

        /** Binds the contact's lookup Uri to the QuickContactBadge*/
        holder.icon.assignContactUri(contactUri);

        /** Loads the thumbnail image pointed to by photoUri into the QuickContactBadge in a
         * background worker thread
         */
        mImageLoader.loadImage(photoUri, holder.icon);
```

After this, I've got this interface, that is called in other activity:

```
public interface OnContactsInteractionListener {
    /**
     * Called when a contact is selected from the ListView.
     * @param contactUri The contact Uri.
     */
    public void onContactSelected(Uri contactUri);
```

This is the main activity where this interface is called, and **where I must implement the function to call to the QuickContact dialog window wich shows the contact information**. **This is what I don't know how to do.**

```
public class ContactsListActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ContactsListFragment.OnContactsInteractionListener {
...

    public void onContactSelected(Uri contactUri) {
        //METHOD TO CALL QUICKCONTACT WINDOW
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just calling this function, I've been able to solve this:

```
QuickContact.showQuickContact(getActivity(), getListView(), uri, position, null);
```